# A functional equation involving the floor function.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let $f$ be a function on the set on non-negative integers and taking values in the same set. Suppose we are given that
>
> - $$x-f(x)=19\left\lfloor \frac{x}{19}\right\rfloor-90\left\lfloor\frac{f(x)}{90}\right\rfloor$$ 
>     for all non-negative integers $x$.
> - $1900<f(1900)<2000$
>
> Find all possible values of $f(1900)$.

In solution given, they have found $f(1990)$ and I just want to check if my solution for $f(1900)$ is correct or not.

My solution:

Let $f(1900)=a$. Substitute $x=1900$ in the first relation.
We have:
$$1900-a=19\left\lfloor\frac{1900}{19}\right\rfloor-90\left\lfloor\frac{a}{90}\right\rfloor$$.
Simplifying,
$$\frac{a}{90}=\left\lfloor\frac{a}{90}\right\rfloor$$
Now, $x=\lfloor x\rfloor$ only when $x$ is an integer. Hence, $a=90k$ where $k$ is an integer.

Now $90k$ must lie between $1900$ and $2000$ giving $k=22$ and $f(1900)=1980$.

Am I correct?

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the simplification and the answer are correct.